# Find the number of lines a string runs into inside a div of a set width (there is no new line separator) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

I have a `div` of a set width inside which I have a `span` that has some text.The styling

```
#web_view_container
{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    width:306px;
    height:202px;
    overflow:auto;  
}
.sentences
{
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:120%;   
}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="web_view_container">    
    <span class="sentences">Hello, This is last sentence This is last sentence This is last sentence This is last sentence This is last sentence.</span>
</div>
```

Now, how would I get the number of lines this `<span>` has run into.

Please note that I am **NOT** using a new line character and so

```
var lines = $('#web_view_container').html().split("\n");  
alert(lines.length);
```

won't work.

This is a fiddle for the same.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrbe/vWhd5/)

Can someone please help me out with this. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the height of the span and divide by the line height. Note that this version doesn't account for padding, margin, etc that could potentially affect the outcome. This works for your example though.

```
// webkit line-height normal consideration thanks to mVChr
var $sent = $('.sentences'),
    lh = $sent.css('line-height'),
    ws = $sent.css('white-space');
if (lh === 'normal') {
    $sent.css('white-space', 'nowrap');
    lh = $sent.height();
    $sent.css('white-space', ws);
}
$('.lines').text(Math.ceil($('.sentences').height() / parseInt(lh, 10)));
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWhd5/13/)**

**[Fiddle without explicit line-height](http://jsfiddle.net/vWhd5/14/)**

*Update*: this does work regardless of margin and padding as `.height()` does not include margin, padding, nor border. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWhd5/15/) has large padding/border/margin and still correctly computes the number of lines.

[image]

*Update 2:* added `Math.ceil()` as partials should always round up for the correct value. Fiddles have been updated.

Comment: it feels hacky but it should be possible to get working (border and padding needs to be subtracted, I think) and I can't think of anything better. +1

Comment: @JanDvorak investigated, does work regardless of border/padding/margin

Comment: Hi Ryan, please check http://jsfiddle.net/skyrbe/qATav/ . It gives me a wrong output even after using `Math.floor()`

Comment: I know that this answer isn't 100% correct. I was also able to find some flaws in @mVChr's answer when I was playing around with font-size and overflow. I'm interested in finding a solution but it will take some time. FYI other solutions I have found for this problem have the same flaws. And depending on what youre doing with this, you should be aware that I doubt any solution will be 100% reliable due to quirks. The best thing would be to find a solution that works for your specific implementation as opposed to a generic one for all scenarios

Comment: Please do let me know if you come across some solution that works irrespective of the font-size . I'll upvote and accept the answer for now :-) Cheers man and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will work even when padding, margin or border on the element is changed:

```
var textLineCount = function(el) {
    var $el = $(el),
        height,
        lineHeight,
        initWhitespace = $el.css('white-space');

    height = $el.height();
    $el.css('white-space', 'nowrap');
    lineHeight = $el.height();
    $el.css('white-space', initWhitespace);

    return Math.floor(height / lineHeight);
};

alert(textLineCount($('.sentences')[0]) + ' lines');
```

Try changing around the CSS for width, padding, margin and border on various elements in the demo.

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vWhd5/3/)

Comment: I don't think that this is necessary, using `innerHeight` and then subtracting padding and border is pointless. See http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/. Also, I updated my answer

Comment: @ryan Updated answer, works even when CSS `line-height` is not set.  Yours would break as `$el.css('line-height')` would return `'normal'`

Comment: @mVChr : Thia shows a wrong line count if I change the `font-size` . Check http://jsfiddle.net/skyrbe/vWhd5/11/

Comment: Math.floor still give me 1 line, i get it right when using Math.ceil